# Opinons: To report or not to report? CFAA vs the White Hat

Tags: research

As I'm sure most people here are aware, there has been quite a lot of attention brought to the USA's Computer Fraud and Abuse Act (CFAA) recently. Brief back story: A security researcher discovered that a cell phone carrier made email addresses of their customers available through a non-authenticated service. He pointed it out and now could spend several decades behind bars.
More Info: http://www.f-secure.com/weblog/archives/00002460.html

Without getting into "#FreeWeev" craze, I'm curious about how security minded folks are processing this information and whether it would deter you from reporting a legitimately identified security concern. Obviously people in the USA will have a bit more context on the issue but I openly welcome all points of view on the issue.

Will these rulings keep you from your work, or change it? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is probably not a good fit for this site, as it appears to be more of an open-ended poll. This is a question-and-answer site, not a discussion site or forum. The site is best-suited for specific technical questions with an objectively definable correct answer. Chatty, open-ended questions, or subjective questions where every answer is equally valid, are off-topic. I encourage you to read through [the FAQ](http://security.stackexchange.com/faq) for more, especially the section labelled [What kind of questions should I not ask here?](http://security.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask).

Answer (score 1):

With respect to how (and whether) to disclose vulnerabilities, that subject has been covered extensively already on this site.

With respect to dealing with a potentially-embarrassing flaw with a powerful organization, remember this little gem:

Powerful organizations do not like to be embarrassed. And one way for them to save face is to incriminate the messenger ("see, we're not irresponsible, he's a terrorist"), and so when doing so, some certain amount of self-protection is in order. Perhaps you should remain anonymous. Perhaps you should seek legal counsel. Perhaps you should work through a third party (e.g. security firm).

Certainly what you should *not* do is flaunt the vulnerability in a spectacle of  sarcastic derision and self-promotion. It may be safe to poke the bear with a long enough stick, but the only way to know for certain is in a post-mortem analysis of the events. Probably best not to poke the bear if you want to stay on the safe side.

Comment: Sound advice. I usually disclose to the vendor anonymously, then disclose it publicly under my own name if it goes well.

Answer (score 0):

This general topic area has been covered at [At what point does "hacking" become illegal? (US)](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/6355/971), which includes references to other security professionals who were affected by these laws.

See also [Found security vulnerability, what should I do?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/13760/971), which covers a related area.